# JSF El variables triggering Application's getResourceBundle

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to provide custom resource bundles to my JSF Application, so I've created and registered in `faces-config.xml` a subclass of `javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory` providing an `Application` with a simple method which is simply logging the access to the `Application` resource bundles:

```
  @Override
  public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(FacesContext ctx, String name) {
    ResourceBundle result = super.getResourceBundle(ctx, name);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0} : {1}", new Object[]{name, result});
    return result;
  }
```

And out of the blue I found that the following XTML code

> ```
>  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.itemList}" var="item">
>    <li><h:outputText value="#{item}"/></li>
>  </ui:repeat>
> ```

is triggering the `getResourceBundle` method, asking if there is a bundle named `item`.

The question is whether this is the expected behavior and how to distinguish such calls from those asking namely for `ResourceBundle` and not for an EL variable.